# iOS 9 syntax for Skype for Business app?

Tags: ios, skype, lync, skype-for-business

We are trying to send a new audio or video call from an iOS 9.2 app to the Skype for Business app.  Below is what we have tried.  Any ideas?

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"business://call?id=name@domain.com"]];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sip://call?id=name@domain.com"]];
```

Comment: maybe "skype:username?call"

Answer (score 1):

The following is from the Microsoft Documentation about skype URI's:

```
BOOL installed = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:"]];
  if(installed)
  {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:echo123?call"]];
  }
  else
  {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.com/apps/skype/skype"]];
  }
```

They do note the following though;
*With the recent redesign of the Skype for iOS client, URIs are not currently supported on the Skype for iOS 5.x branch.*

This might not apply to Skype for Business, but unless documented elsewhere. It's worth a try.

To determine which URL you need, check the following documentation for Skype URIs:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn745882.aspx